# AVCaptureSession "output sample buffer" reading pixel coordinate gives a wrong color

Tags: ios, pixel, avcapturesession

I use AVCaptureSession to initiate a video capture session and read pixel colors from video frames. The video setting is like this.

```
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA],
                               kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                               nil];
```

with a delegate method below to get sample buffer, which I will later read pixel colors.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput // captureOutput is only the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{ 

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new]; // instrument tells it leaks

    /*******  START CALCULATION  *******/

    imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0); // lock image buffer
    buffer_baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); // raw buffer data BGRA

...
```

The variable `buffer_baseAddress` is an array that stores pixel colors, in which under `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` setting, the array will arrange like 
[B][G][R][A][B][G][R][A][B]...[B][G][R][A]. So to get a color at pixel at some coordinate, I'll have to figure out 3 indices in the buffer. So at (x,y) = (10,0), BGR will be at index 40, 41, and 42.

Here is the problem. The first row (y == 0) of the sample buffer seems to give correct color at all times. But when I move to the second row onward (y > 0), I got wrong colors on some presets, or using front/back camera. **It's like the buffer has some unknown, extra data appended at the end of each row, in a certain setting.** Luckily from my experiments, I find that sample buffers got shifted by some amount in each row when I use **AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh on back Camera, and AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium on both front/back cameras**. I remembered setting some rowPadding = 0 in one of AVCaptureSession class doesn't help either. (I'm sorry I forgot what exact variable it was. It was several months back.)

What causes this problem? And what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the section [Converting a CMSampleBuffer to a UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/06_MediaRepresentations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH2-SW16) in this page from the Apple Docs. I haven't tried it but it shows how to get the `bytesPerRow` - including padding - of the buffer.

It is normal for an image buffer to be padded to an optimal value, whether you are using CoreVideo, CoreImage, Quartz, Quicktime etc.. there will always be a way to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution. Not the best one but it helps me get across it. I just test each of every `AVCaptureSessionPreset` and see which one got wrong pixels read. Then I try to guess the size of that extra padding and use it when I calculate the sample buffer index. **This magic number is 8**, took me days to find this out. So hopefully this will be helpful to someone, at least, as a workaround. :-)

```
    // Look like this magic padding is affected by AVCaptureSessionPreset and front/back camera
    if ([[self currentPresetSetting] isEqualToString:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh] && ![self isUsingFrontFacingCamera]) {
        buffer_rowPixelPadding = 8;
    }
    else if ([[self currentPresetSetting] isEqualToString:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium]) {
        buffer_rowPixelPadding = 8;
    }
    else {
        buffer_rowPixelPadding = 0; // default
    }
```